# CouchDB 3-node cluster (Windows) - multiple erlang errors

Tags: windows, erlang, couchdb

Im receiving multiple erlang errors in my CouchDB 2.1.1 cluster (3 nodes/Windows), see errors and node configuration below:

3 nodes (10.0.7.4 - 10.0.7.6), Azure application gateway is used as load balancer.
Why do these errors appear? system resources of the nodes are far from overload.

I would be thankful for any help - thanks in advance.

**Errors:**

```
rexi_server: from: couchdb@10.0.7.4(<0.14976.568>) mfa: fabric_rpc:changes/3 exit:timeout [{rexi,init_stream,1,[{file,"src/rexi.erl"},{line,256}]},{rexi,stream_last,2,[{file,"src/rexi.erl"},{line,224}]},{fabric_rpc,changes,4,[{file,"src/fabric_rpc.erl"},{line,86}]},{rexi_server,init_p,3,[{file,"src/rexi_server.erl"},{line,139}]}]

rexi_server: from: couchdb@10.0.7.6(<13540.24597.655>) mfa: fabric_rpc:all_docs/3 exit:timeout [{rexi,init_stream,1,[{file,"src/rexi.erl"},{line,256}]},{rexi,stream2,3,[{file,"src/rexi.erl"},{line,204}]},{fabric_rpc,view_cb,2,[{file,"src/fabric_rpc.erl"},{line,308}]},{couch_mrview,finish_fold,2,[{file,"src/couch_mrview.erl"},{line,642}]},{rexi_server,init_p,3,[{file,"src/rexi_server.erl"},{line,139}]}]

rexi_server: from: couchdb@10.0.7.6(<13540.5991.623>) mfa: fabric_rpc:all_docs/3 exit:timeout [{rexi,init_stream,1,[{file,"src/rexi.erl"},{line,256}]},{rexi,stream2,3,[{file,"src/rexi.erl"},{line,204}]},{fabric_rpc,view_cb,2,[{file,"src/fabric_rpc.erl"},{line,308}]},{couch_mrview,map_fold,3,[{file,"src/couch_mrview.erl"},{line,511}]},{couch_btree,stream_kv_node2,8,[{file,"src/couch_btree.erl"},{line,848}]},{couch_btree,fold,4,[{file,"src/couch_btree.erl"},{line,222}]},{couch_db,enum_docs,5,[{file,"src/couch_db.erl"},{line,1450}]},{couch_mrview,all_docs_fold,4,[{file,"src/couch_mrview.erl"},{line,425}]}]

req_err(3206982071) unknown_error : normal [<<"mochiweb_request:recv/3 L180">>,<<"mochiweb_request:stream_unchunked_body/4 L540">>,<<"mochiweb_request:recv_body/2 L214">>,<<"chttpd:body/1 L636">>,<<"chttpd:json_body/1 L649">>,<<"chttpd:json_body_obj/1 L657">>,<<"chttpd_db:db_req/2 L386">>,<<"chttpd:process_request/1 L295">>]

System running to use fully qualified hostnames ** ** Hostname localhost is illegal
```

**COMPACTION-ERRORS**

```
Supervisor couch_secondary_services had child compaction_daemon started with couch_compaction_daemon:start_link() at <0.18509.478> exit with reason {compaction_loop_died,{timeout,{gen_server,call,[couch_server,get_server]}}} in context child_terminated 

 CRASH REPORT Process couch_compaction_daemon (<0.18509.478>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {compaction_loop_died,{timeout,{gen_server,call,[couch_server,get_server]}}} at gen_server:terminate/7(line:826) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_compaction_daemon,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [couch_secondary_services,couch_sup,<0.200.0>], messages: [], links: [<0.12665.492>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: true, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 27, reductions: 3173

gen_server couch_compaction_daemon terminated with reason: {compaction_loop_died,{timeout,{gen_server,call,[couch_server,get_server]}}} last msg: {'EXIT',<0.23195.476>,{timeout,{gen_server,call,[couch_server,get_server]}}} state: {state,<0.23195.476>,[]}  

Error in process <0.16890.22> on node 'couchdb@10.0.7.4' with exit value: {{rexi_DOWN,{'couchdb@10.0.7.5',noproc}},[{mem3_rpc,rexi_call,2,[{file,"src/mem3_rpc.erl"},{line,269}]},{mem3_rep,calculate_start_seq,1,[{file,"src/mem3_rep.erl"},{line,194}]},{mem3_rep,repl,2,[{file,"src/mem3_rep.erl"},{line,175}]},{mem3_rep,go,1,[{file,"src/mem3_rep.erl"},{line,81}]},{mem3_sync,'-start_push_replication/1-fun-0-',2,[{file,"src/mem3_sync.erl"},{line,208}]}]}
```

**#vm.args**

```
-name couchdb@10.0.7.4
-setcookie monster
-kernel error_logger silent
-sasl sasl_error_logger false
+K true
+A 16
+Bd -noinput
+Q 134217727`
```

**local.ini**

```
[fabric]
request_timeout = infinity

[couchdb]
max_dbs_open = 10000
os_process_timeout = 20000
uuid =

[chttpd]
port = 5984
bind_address = 0.0.0.0

[httpd]
socket_options = [{recbuf, 262144}, {sndbuf, 262144}, {nodelay, true}]
enable_cors = true

[couch_httpd_auth]
secret =

[daemons]
compaction_daemon={couch_compaction_daemon, start_link, []}

[compactions]
_default = [{db_fragmentation, "50%"}, {view_fragmentation, "50%"}, {from, "23:00"}, {to, "04:00"}]

[compaction_daemon]
check_interval = 300
min_file_size = 100000

[vendor]
name = COUCHCLUSTERNODE0X

[admins]
adminuser =

[cors]
methods = GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE
headers = accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer
origins = *
credentials = true

[query_server_config]
os_process_limit = 2000
os_process_soft_limit = 1000
```

Comment: You could check if your firewall is not allowing communication between ports. Have you checked the erlang cluster configuration as proposed in de doc? http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/cluster/setup.html

Comment: Hello Jaunjo, thx for the hint - sys.config wasn't edited on all nodes which I did today. I'll update this if this solved the error.